# Python matplotlib line chart - setting ylim value

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts

I'm creating a solution that should parse results from JUnit XML (performance tests, ram used/ram free) and create a line chart. Basically I got all up and running but I have problem with setting up the ylim value to tick on Y axis values from 0 - 100 (%) so that on chart I have full view of the percentage. 
At this moment I'm able to generate something like that:

[image: Imgur]

What is missing here that I want to achieve is the 'empty' Y axis below (from 0%) and up (up to 100%). I'm using the set_ylim method:

```
    chart_fig, chart_ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 4))
    chart_ax.plot(parsed_testcase_results[0]['x_axis_values'], parsed_testcase_results[0]['y_axis_values'], 'g',
                  parsed_testcase_results[1]['x_axis_values'], parsed_testcase_results[1]['y_axis_values'], 'r')
    chart_ax.set(xlabel='time (s)', ylabel='percentage (%)')
    chart_ax.grid()
    chart_ax.autoscale(False)
    chart_ax.set_xticks([x for x in range(0, max(parsed_testcase_results[0]['x_axis_values']), 10)])
    chart_ax.set_xlim(min(parsed_testcase_results[0]['x_axis_values']), max(parsed_testcase_results[0]['x_axis_values']))
    # chart_ax.set_ylim([0, 100])
    chart_fig.savefig('test.png')
```

parsed_testcase_results is a dict with x and y values + label for chart (it is simplified not to add too much text in the post):

```
[{
    'property_name': 'RAM used',
    'x_axis_values': array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]),
    'y_axis_values': array(['31.70', '31.70', '31.70', '31.70', '31.70', '31.70', '31.70'])
}, {
    'property_name': 'RAM free',
    'x_axis_values': array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]),
    'y_axis_values': array(['68.29', '68.29', '68.29', '68.29', '68.29', '68.29', '68.29']
    }
]
```

But when I uncomment line that should set ylim I got this creep:

[image: Imgur]

From the image itself I assume that [0,100] limit is being drawn above the charts not from the charts itself. Anyone has idea how to fix that?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: The problem is that your `y` values are strings -- try converting them to floats before plotting.

Comment: Yep, thats it... I even didn't noticed this. Thanks!